# Double sampling method in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array

My initial code for double sampling is the following. I did only one sample.

```
# Data
samples<-matrix(NA,nrow = 12, ncol = 2000)
for (i in 1:12) {
    samples[i,]<- rbinom(2000,1,prob = 0.05)
}
# Double Sampling Plan
accept<-rep(0,12)
for (i  in 1:12) {
    if (sum(samples[i,1:80])<=5){
        accept[i]<-1
    } else if (sum(samples[i,1:80]<=8) & sum(samples[i,1:80]>5) ) {
        if (sum(samples[i,1:160])<=12) {
            accept[i]<-1
        }
    }
}
sum(accept)
```

Since I generated randomly from Bernoulli, every time you run the code, the results will not be the same.

I want 100 repetitions of this double sample.

My solution:

```
nm=double(100)
for (j in 1:100){
    # Data
    samples<-matrix(NA,nrow = 12, ncol = 2000)
    for (i in 1:12) {
        samples[i,]<- rbinom(2000,1,prob = 0.05)
    }

    # Double Sampling Plan
    accept<-rep(0,12)
    for (i  in 1:12) {
        if (sum(samples[i,1:80])<=5){
            accept[i]<-1
        } else if (sum(samples[i,1:80]<=8) & sum(samples[i,1:80]>5) ) {
            if (sum(samples[i,1:160])<=12) {
                accept[i]<-1
            }
        }
    }
    nm[j]=sum(accept)
}
mean(nm)
```

What do you think?

Comment: One good practice when you simulate random variables is to use `set.seed()` function. See their for double sampling explanation https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section2/pmc24.htm

Comment: use functions. just write a function that produces what you want in 1 case. then replicate that 100 times

Comment: @Rémi Coulaud thanks. What do you think about the rest code?

Comment: I answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If we follow the proposition of @Onyambu, we can embeded one simulation inside a function and call it in a loop like this :

```
one_double_sampling <- function(){
    # Data
    samples<-matrix(NA,nrow = 12, ncol = 2000)
    for (i in 1:12) {
        samples[i,]<- rbinom(2000,1,prob = 0.05)
    }
    # Double Sampling Plan
    accept<-rep(0,12)
    for (i  in 1:12) {
        if (sum(samples[i, 1:80])<=5){
            accept[i]<-1
        } else if (sum(samples[i,1:80]<=8) & sum(samples[i,1:80]>5) ) {
            if (sum(samples[i,1:160])<=12) {
                accept[i]<-1
            }
        }
    }
    return(sum(accept))
}

set.seed(123)

# number of sample
n <- 100

# stock the result
res <- rep(0, n)
for(i in 1:n){
    res[i] <- one_double_sampling()
}

# mean
mean(res)
```

Definitly your code is correct. For people interresting by the double sampling method I advise you to see [this](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section2/pmc24.htm).

**Edit 1**

In one line code based on Onyambu advise :

```
mean(replicate(n,  one_double_sampling()))
```

Comment: just do `mean(replicate(100, one_double_sampling()))`